# Rails Application appear Errors after upgrade to Rails 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After I upgrade my Rails app from 5.0.2 to 5.1.1, errors appear like that:

No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions"

```
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:106:in `assert_index'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:80:in `insert_after'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:69:in `block in merge_into'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:68:in `each'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:68:in `merge_into'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:507:in `block in app'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:45:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/Users/thiensubs/Documents/super-control/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => middleware => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My ruby version is: 2.4.1

Older Rails version is: 5.0.2

My lasted version is: 5.1.1

Any body can help me with that?

Comment: Do you set config to api only = true ? Seems like some middleware is missing

Comment: Do you happen to have the remotipart gem installed?

Comment: I was add remotipart lasted version, but it still networking,

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and after grepping `insert_after` method in my gem folders, it was an outdated `airbrake` gem which causes the problem.

Relax the version in Gemfile and `bundle update airbrake` seems to fix it.